# Localhost style different from server style

Tags: html, css, server, localhost

In order to create a website, I first worked with MAMP in a local mode. 
After finishing the index page, I uploaded it. 
The problem is that the images on the website are bigger than in the localhost for the index page.

I inspected the elements, but the style applied to each div are same.

I used "px" as unit of length to display the images.

I don't understand why two elements styles can be different while their codes are same.

Comment: This sounds obvious, but did you make sure your not zoomed in on any of the pages?

Comment: I feel like an idiot now, that was the solution ... it was too obvious that I didn't even think about it.
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: Haha no problem! I could totally see myself doing that so that's the only reason I thought of it

Answer (score 0):

I think i know whats your problem.
It's a cache problem.

Delete your cache and check it out.

For developers there is a function called "Disable Cache" you can find it , for example, in Google Chrome here: https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache

Edit:

Clear cache in Google Chrome: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried to delete the cache, it didn't work.
I also tried to use a different web browser (safari) which shows the same result. The first web browser was google chrome.